# Fill raster nodata from other rasters

Tags: raster, r

There are 5 rasters: `r0`, `r1`,`r2`,`r3`,`r4` with same extent, columns and rows. Random nodata cell disperse in each raster. Now I expect to fill nodata values of `r0` with mean values of the other rasters in the same position(the cell of same row and column number). Of course, the mean values of cell exclude nodata values. I can not find function in `raster` package.
Actually, the basic function I expect is like 'con' in `arcmap`.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the mean of rasters ignoring NA values:

```
mean(r1,r2,r3,r4,na.rm=TRUE)
```

To replace NA values in raster `r0` with values from the mean of rasters:

```
r0[is.na(r0)] = mean(r1,r2,r3,r4,na.rm=TRUE)[is.na(r0)]
```

There's a little overhead there since you are computing the mean over all the raster and throwing away everything you don't need to fill in the NAs in `r0`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I omited description of raster. If all of cells in one position of `r1`,`r2`,`r3`,`r4` are nodata, using `na.rm` will cause the mean value is zero. Because The rasters are extracted by shp file, so that outside of shp is defined as nodata. I don't expect calculate these cell when applied function `mean`.@Spacedman

Comment: Create some simple rasters for examples. eg `r1 = raster(matrix(1:12,3,4));r1[1,1]=NA`. Repeat for the other rasters and then tell us what the expected output is.